# Change Values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change values in a dictionary.
for example I want to change the value **'Available'** to **'Not Available'**

```py
book_library_dict = {
    1: [1, 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows', 'Bloomsbury', 'J K Rowling', 'Available', None, }
```

Comment: So what's preventing you from making that change?

Comment: I don't know how I'm still learning :(

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So, what does the value `'Available'` mean to you? How do you currently extract that value from the `dict`?

Comment: What's stopping you from continuing learning? SO is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax to refer to value stored in the key 1:

```
book_library_dict[1]
```

In this case, the value stored in the key `1` is a list, so you can do the following to replace the element `Available` with `Not Available`.

```
book_library_dict[1][book_library_dict[1].index('Available)] = 'Not Available'
```

This is not very pretty, so you might want to consider changing your variable structure to be a list of dictionaries. Something like:

```
book_library_dict = {
1: {'Number': 1, Title: 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows', 
   ... 'Avilabaility': 'Available', ... }
```

You could then change the value with

```
book_library_dict[1]['Availability'] = 'Not Available'
```